# Compass(HMC5883L) interfacing with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python

Heloo folks, i am planning to interface a digital compass to Raspi, i am using **Python 2.X** i tried a lot for libraries but no use, i got a few of them but they were meant to use with **Python 3.X** but my in project till now i interfaced a few thing with Python 2.7 can any one help me with this? I tried a lot and **am not posting without trying**, when i try to detect the compass address is **1e** ,which i saw in terminal i am using **Raspian Wheezy.** i am trying to make **autonomous vehicle** guided by **GPS and compass** i am done with everything except this Compass integration, which python 2.x modules to ue? i want to know in which direction i am heading using a compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution i am using smbus module and code is referred from [here](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/connecting-and-calibrating-hmc5883l.html), if you are using old raspi boards then use`bus = smbus.SMBus(0)`(rev 1) or else use`bus = smbus.SMBus(1)`. smbus module usage and i2c tutorial can be found  [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-python/i2c-programming-in-python/using-the-i2c-interface-2).

Comment: great that you found a solution - please mark your answer as correct, so the question will not appear to be open. Thanks!